# Keys randomly pressing themselves

Tags: keyboard

I have an HP Probook 440.

Sometimes I will press a key and another random key gets pressed with it. For example, just a moment ago I used the right arrow key. The 'n' character was entered into the document even though my finger was nowhere near it.

Sometimes the super key is pressed, sometimes the print-screen is pressed. I am pretty sure that about 1 in every 100 keystrokes there is a random key that sends a signal saying, "I was pressed!" when it wasn't.

So what could be causing that?

Comment: How old is this HP Probook 440? Have you ever spilled anything on the keyboard? Was it purchased new or used? What this comes down to is keyboards are actually matrixes of connections. And what this all sounds like is there is some short circuit in the keyboard matrix that is causing these incorrect keypresses.

Comment: I've had it for three months. It was purchased used...

Comment: Okay, if you bought it used it could be damaged goods the seller is trying to pass off as working. I recommend you return it for a full refund and take your money elsewhere.

Comment: Also check for swollen battery pressing on keyboard, if internal.

Comment: I have already opened it to install memory and a hard drive, so I can't in good conscience blame the seller. I plan to clean the contacts with IPA, check for parts pressing against other parts etc.

Answer (score 1):

Either its a genuine hardware fault.  Or something has been spilt on the keyboard.  From my, experience, the most common liquids are

- coffee
- coke
- juice
- cat wee (dont't laugh, it's common)

If it's because something has been spilled, you can fix it.  You need to

- open up the keyboard,
- spray/drench it with IPA,
- gently scrub, especially any smudges
- gently wipe
- let it dry
- close it up again.

**Being a laptop, you need to be more careful.**

Comment: I downvoted this because while well intentioned, it is basically just a list of hunches and ideas and not a real answer. I agree with much of what you wrote but it would work better as a comment. Especially in the context of  the original poster indicating the PC was purchased used.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think it should be mandatory.  Two reasons for not being a comment.  1) I couldn't format it for it to be useful.  2) I felt it may help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

After opening it closing it again the problem seems to have stopped for now. My educated guess is that some of the screws on the back were too tight.

Accessing the contacts on this model is way to difficult. It would be easiest to take each key off and clean them one-by-one.